# quickstart error - Using EF Migrations for local SQL Server and keep loosing db connection

Tags: entity-framework-core, identityserver4, entity-framework-migrations

I am following IdentityServer4 quickstart and trying to migrate in memory data to my local SQL Server (not SQL express or LocalDB that came with VS). My connection string is:

@"Server=localhost,1434;Database=MyIDS;user id=tester_1;Password=tester_1;trusted_connection=yes;".

When I start my IdentityServer, it creates the enpty db, MyIDS, and then throw an exception with 2 inner exceptions:

Inner Exception 1:
SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.)

Inner Exception 2:
Win32Exception: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? Why a working connection always gets dropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localhost,1434 looks wrong, you don't need to provide the port 1434 and the commma should not be used either, it should be a colon in that case.

I typically use for local development:

```
server=.;Database=ASPIdentity;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

dot means localhost, if you use sqlexpress the connetion string would become

```
server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=ASPIdentity;Trusted_Connection=True;
```